# Hide Button when type a string on url in Dot.Net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I need your help as I have the following situation:
I have a button called 'UPDATE' with **ID="Update"**, it will be hidden most of the time, but I'd like it visible when I type some string to my URL, such as: 
**URL = localhost:80** and I'd like to add **?string=updateme**
How can I code this on my aspnet VB loadPage?

Thanks is advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will guide you in the right direction.

```
If (Not (Request.QueryString("string")) Is Nothing) Then
    If (Request.QueryString("string").ToString = "updateme") Then
        Update.Visible = true
    End If    
End If
```

Or

```
If Request.Url.ToString.Contains("localhost") Then
    Update.Visible = true
End If
```

PS code is translated from C# to VB with http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/, so it may not be 100% correct.

Comment: Thanks VDWWD, I'll try it tomorrow and let you know,but thanks anyway